# AngularJS passing Json to controller and displaying in a DevExpress Chart

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, database, angularjs, devexpress

I have a JsonResult method in my controller.  I have pulled in data from my database and set to an object.  The method will return this object.  I am trying pass this data into AngularJS data source.  I would like to display a DevExtreme bar chart.  Here is code so far.

AngularJS file:

```
var app = angular.module('customApp', ['dx']);
app.controller("chartControl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sizeSettings = {
        dataSource: 'http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart',
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            argumentField: 'product_id',
            valueField: "product_id", name: "Product Cost",
            type: "bar"
        },
        seriesTemplate: {
            nameField: 'Source',
        }
    };
});
```

Home Controller:

```
public JsonResult PostChart(int product_id)
    {
        Object prod = null;
        using (ProductOrderEntities db = new ProductOrderEntities())
        {
            var product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.product_id == product_id);
            prod = new {productID = product.product_id, productName = product.product_name, productPrice = product.product_cost, productDescription = product.product_type};                
        }
        return Json(prod, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="customApp">
    <div ng-controller="chartControl">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="customCharts">
    <div ng-controller="ChartController">
        <div dx-chart="productSettings"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function () {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                });
                return def.promise();
            }
        }),
        series: {
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            argumentType: String,
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount'
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult PostChart()
        {
            var prod = new List<Object>();
            using (ProductOrderEntities db = new ProductOrderEntities())
            {
                var product = db.Products.ToList();
                foreach (var p in product)
                {
                    var thing = new { Name = p.product_name, Cost = p.product_cost };
                    prod.Add(thing);
                }
            }
            return Json(prod, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget add markup for chart:

```
<div dx-chart="chartOptions"></div>
```

I've made a simple ASP.NET MVC application here https://www.dropbox.com/s/hk3viceoa2zkyng/DevExtremeChart.zip?dl=0

Open the start page http://localhost:56158/Default1/ to see chart in action.

See more information about using DevExtreme Charts in AngularJS app here http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Basics/Create_a_Widget/?version=14_2#Data_Visualization_Basics_Create_a_Widget_Add_a_Widget_AngularJS_Approach

Comment: Thank you for your example.  This is great.  I did make a few changes after posting this and when I try to mirror your example, I am still not displaying the widget.  I think it has something to do with how the Json list is being called in my AngularJS file.  Here is a zip file of my project: Any thoughts? https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyx0u2k0r249hvg/DashboardExample%20-%20Copy.zip?dl=0

Comment: Nevermind. I changed some things up and this worked. Thanks again!